# hibernate left join with multiple where conditions

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

------I am writing sql query its works fine ------------------

```
SELECT SUM (lb.QUANTITY*mp.DB_PRICE) 
FROM ledger_balance lb 
LEFT JOIN material_price mp ON (mp.MATERIAL_ID = lb.MATERIAL_ID) 
WHERE lb.QTY_TYPE ='G' 
AND lb.BALANCE_TYPE='CUMU' 
AND lb.CUSTOMER_ID = 13
AND mp.CUSTOMER_ID = 13 AND  lb.MATERIAL_ID IN (226, 230, 362, 365)
AND mp.MATERIAL_ID IN (226, 230, 362, 365);
```

--- hibernate query its not working ------

```
SELECT SUM (B.quantity*P.dbPrice) 
FROM com.efl.efms.data.domain.common.LedgerBalance as B 
LEFT JOIN com.efl.efms.data.domain.material.MaterialPrice as P   
with (B.materialId = P.materialCatalog.materialId)  
WHERE   B.balanceType=:balanceType 
AND B.qtyType=:qtyType and B.customerId in (:customerId) AND P.customer.customerId IN (:customerId)  
AND B.materialId in (:materialPriceId)  
AND P.materialCatalog.materialId in (:materialPriceId) ;
```

Please help me hibernate left join and I am getting following error while doing left join
`hibernate java.lang.illegalstateexception` dot node with no left-hand-side

Answer (score 7):

You can't join on non mapped relationships with Hibernate.

If you have a query that returns only unstructured data (in your case a number), I would tend to use native queries.

- you don't have to waste time to translate your query into HQL
- it runs faster because all of Hibernate's translation processes can be
  ommitted

Comment: you should post a code example for how to solve this to make your answer more complete. nevertheless helped me a lot, +1